# Implement XOR statement for break_intervals on or-tools using Python

Tags: python, constraint-programming, or-tools

I've been recently working with or-tools and now I'm playing around with break intervals for CVRP using python.

What I want to achieve is creating N number of breaks for a vehicle and place on top a XOR constraint, so one and only one of the breaks is performed.

I've create the breaks  and a list of the performed values of each break interval as follow:

```
 for i in xrange(len(self.breaks)):
     name_break = "break_{}".format(i)
     start_min, start_max, duration_break = breaks[i]
     optional_break = True

     break_intervals.append(solver.FixedDurationIntervalVar(start_min, start_max, duration_break, optional_break, name_break))
     performed_values.add(break_intervals[i].PerformedExpr())
```

Then I use the syntactic sugar of *solver* to add a constraint using the *SumEquality* method and add the break intervals to the vehicle:

```
solver.Add(solver.SumEquality(performed_values, 1))
```

`routing.GetDimensionOrDie("Time").SetBreakIntervalsOfVehicle(break_intervals, 0)`

The constraint works perfectly when there is only one break in *breaks* (which is the same as change the value of 'optional_break' to *False*). Problem is when I add a new break in *breaks*, there is no solution. *Assignment* is empty.

The solution is feasible, with the first break I get an assignment and adding one *optional*  break shouldn't return a null assignment.

I've followed pretty much this [cpp tutorial](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/cpp/cvrptw_with_breaks.cc#L84), except for the break interval constraints and *minimize time variables* statements.

Perhaps I'm missing something. Do you have any insight about the issue?